# Rails 7 precompile assets in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Hi**

my Rails-7.0.4 app is not precompiling assets in development as expected

**expected**

it should refresh styles on browser reload in development

**current behaviour**

by example adding a style to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`
i have to do `rails assets:precompile` manually and then restart the server.
just precompile or just restart doesnt refresh the styles.

**what i`ve done**

i added `config.assets.compile = true` to `environments/development.rb`
it changed nothing, and, i assume that this is default anyhow.

i also tested the gem `hotwire-livereload`
on changing views ist working super-fast and refreshes properly
but, refreshing the stylesheets it has no affect to the above mentioned behaviour

**can it be** i started with this app on Rails-7.0.2, updated then to rails-7.0.3, by changing the gem in the gemfile. Can that have an affect?

**Thanks,
Chris**

Answer (score 2):

Just run your server with `bin/dev` instead of `bin/rails s`

**Update**

If you don't have this file you can add it to `bin` folder

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if ! command -v foreman &> /dev/null
then
  echo "Installing foreman..."
  gem install foreman
fi

foreman start -f Procfile.dev
```

and `Procfile.dev` in the root of your application

```rb
web: bin/rails server -p 3000
css: yarn build:css --watch
```

Comment: that was what i searched for, but inside `bin/` is no binary "dev". I installed one app new by `rails new testapp` which is 7.0.3, and there also is no binary "dev"

Comment: Check my update

Comment: Thanks, Stefanyuk! Now we have 2 working ways :)

Comment: @YuriiStefaniuk this fixed my issue, thanks. I wonder why it happened to my Rails setup after a full year without problems using `rails s`.
This morning, it doesn't do hot reloading of assets compiled with Yarn.
@chmich please mark this answer as solving if it did it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Now i built the whole app new `rails new app-name` (v 7.0.3) and draged all contents from the previous app there. App is started by `rails s` with the gem `hotwire-livereload`, live-reloading included works like expected. So, i can not tell why, but it works now.